# How to implement RTMP/RTSP protocol for sending video to server ios(live streaming)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ffmpeg, rtmp

Anybody know how to use FFMpeg for live streaming in ios? Where do I download the FFMpeg library from? Can somebody give some hint about where to start? I don't have any code in this question because I have no idea what to ask.

Any link where I can start with will be a great help. All the answers for similar questions are outdated. There are no proper tutorials also.

Comment: check out this .. https://kickflip.io/

Comment: Have you used this?Can we link our server with kickflip?